# How to print the reason for program exit / program termination / exit errors?

Tags: python, exit, termination

I managed to catch the termination with:

```
atexit.register(exitHandler)
```

But how to print out what happened on that point? I want to see if the program aborts due to an error, due to Crtl-C or normal stopping...

Answer (score 0):

It's not the complete solution - but you could wrap code in try except

```
try:
    YOUR CODE HERE

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: @UlrichBien: Sure you can — just define a `main()` function and call it within the `try`/`except`.

Comment: @UlrichBien You definitely can (or at least I do, especially when debugging).

Answer (score 0):

You should catch `KeyboardInterrupt` for Ctrl-C. E.g.:

```py
import sys


try:
    # your code
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit('Abort by user interrupt')
except Exception as exc:
    sys.exit(f'Abort on error: {exc}')
```